# What is the content value for this arrow facing down?

Tags: winrt-xaml

I am trying to create expand/collapse buttons who's content looks like this:
http://www.geekchamp.com/icon-explorer/settings-icons/icon?code=e26b
except facing down or up (instead of left and right), and taking up more of the circle.

I can rotate the button like this:

```
<Button Content="&#xE26B;" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

But it doesn't look as good as if i were to find the content that just looked like I wanted it to.

Anybody know the content value I should use? Or does anyone know how I can look up the content value? I looked through this site pretty thoroughly, but didn't find it. Are there any other sites like it?
http://www.geekchamp.com/icon-explorer/introduction

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, in all reality, you don't want to use a character from the character map because you can't have absolute control over its placement; in the `TextBlock` the font character has nasty internal spacing you can't control. If pixel-perfect UI matters to you, you know what I mean.

**Let's use this fool-proof solution!**

It doesn't mean it has to be complicated either. Just do this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ArrowRight">
            <Path Width="50" Height="50" Data="F1M568.254,-7.43524L568.159,-7.34277 567.977,-7.52246 546.559,-28.9417 525.484,-28.9417 549.787,-4.63446 557.439,3.01532 557.619,3.19629 550.067,10.7549 525.758,35.0583 546.834,35.0583 568.254,13.6429 578.792,3.10254 568.254,-7.43524z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ArrowDown">
            <Path Width="50" Height="50" Data="F1M181.297,177.841L181.205,177.746 181.385,177.563 202.804,156.146 202.804,135.07 178.497,159.373 170.847,167.026 170.666,167.205 163.107,159.653 138.804,135.345 138.804,156.42 160.219,177.841 170.76,188.379 181.297,177.841z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ArrowLeft">
            <Path Width="50" Height="50" Data="F1M646.688,13.5518L646.783,13.4593 646.965,13.639 668.383,35.0583 689.459,35.0583 665.155,10.751 657.503,3.10126 657.323,2.92023 664.876,-4.63837 689.184,-28.9417 668.109,-28.9417 646.688,-7.52637 636.15,3.01398 646.688,13.5518z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ArrowUp">
            <Path Width="50" Height="50" Data="F1M753.644,-13.0589L753.736,-12.9639 753.557,-12.7816 732.137,8.63641 732.137,29.7119 756.445,5.40851 764.094,-2.24384 764.275,-2.42352 771.834,5.1286 796.137,29.4372 796.137,8.36163 774.722,-13.0589 764.181,-23.5967 753.644,-13.0589z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <!-- arrows -->
    <ContentControl Margin="10" Template="{StaticResource ArrowRight}" />
    <ContentControl Margin="10" Template="{StaticResource ArrowDown}" />
    <ContentControl Margin="10" Template="{StaticResource ArrowLeft}" />
    <ContentControl Margin="10" Template="{StaticResource ArrowUp}" />

</StackPanel>
```

Put the resources up in App.xaml and you can use this everywhere in your app by just using the `ContentControl` wherever you want the glyph. And in your animations, you just swap one template for another or, if you want to be cool, apply a rotation. Either way, this is the fool-proof low-tech approach. I would recommend this before I would ever use a font character.

Looks like this:

[image]

The spacing around the glyphs is 100% perfect and you can manipulate them to your app.

To drive the point home

Look how terrible the character-approach looks as you start to rotate them (if, for example, you wanted to use a cool animation in a visual state transition).

Using this code:

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol" />
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value=".5,.5" />
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="&#xE26B;">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="&#xE26B;">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="&#xE26B;">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="&#xE26B;">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

It would result in this terrible UI:

[image]

See how the alignment is screwed up because they aren't properly centered?

You might be asking, okay, what if I used the 4 characters without rotation. Of course this means you would want to use the character map to find the chars. Not a big deal.

> aside: the narrow character you used in your question does not have all four directions so you have to use the fatter one I am using here.

Using this:

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol" />
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="&#xE0E2;" />
<TextBlock Text="&#xE0E3;" />
<TextBlock Text="&#xE0E4;" />
<TextBlock Text="&#xE0E5;" />
```

It looks initially perfect, like this:

[image]

As beautifully perfect as they might appear, the reality is that they are not a square. You might ask, so what if I gave them a height and width that were equal. That makes a square, right? Yes. But look how it positioned the resulting character in the control:

[image]

> aside: you might be thinking `Padding` is another option to you, but you would be wrong because `Padding` doesn't influence `TextBlock` content like other controls.

Here you can really see how the character isn't in the center in the first place. As a result, once you have attempted to layout the `TextBlock`, you have made animations a VERY difficult option. Even if you don't care about animations in your UI (though you should), the `Path` approach at the top is the wisest because it gives you the most control over general layout over a character.

I hope this makes sense why symbol characters are handy but not ideal.

Best of luck!

Comment: Very thorough response. Thanks for taking the time to explain!

Answer (score 2):

There is a little program called Character Map that comes with Windows. You can use it to lookup character codes.

Comment: Except that you need a magnifier to be able to see the small glyphs, search doesn't actually finds these glyphs Mike asks about and in general I think it doesn't actually display all glyphs available in the font.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your responses. As for the character map suggestion, is there a way of translating the code at the bottom of character map to the code that is used in for the content value in my example? For instance, my example has Content="&#xE26B;", which is the arrow pointing right. In character map, it is U+02C3. The character code of the character I want is U+02C5. Is there a way to translate U+02C5 into something that starts with "&#xE" that would be suitable to stick in the content attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably trace the icon fairly easily in Blend, but it might not actually be worth the effort. What you are doing with a `RotateTransform` should be just fine unless you have a specific problem with it (other than the 4 more lines of XAML or other alignment problems).

Comment: Trace it in Design! http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36180

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button  Content="&#8744;"  Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Foreground="White" />
```

or

```
<Button  Content="&#709;"  Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Foreground="White" />
```

These websites were helpful:
http://www.ebyte.it/library/educards/html/HTMLEntitiesAndGlyphs.html
http://unicode-table.com/en/#spacing-modifier-letters

I dont think I would have known what to look for, had Filip not mentioned the word Glyph. Thanks for both of your responses.

Comment: Glad you are happy, though these are not the same as the once you started with and I think they don't look as good as the next/previous icons.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. You might change your mind.